# How to update android COSU apps

Tags: android, cosu

I am trying to make one android application which is implemented using android COSU. But I am stuck now to update the app, few doubts that comes in my mind:

1) After updation what about the Device Owner Privileges that were set up earlier ?

2) We will block Play store as well as any other application usage in the devices. So how to update the COSU app that it retains the requirements?

3) How to update the app in COUS mode ? Procedures.

4) Minimum android API level that will be required?

Awaiting for a response.
a

Comment: did you get the answer? Also, if I set the play account and upload apk on play store then still will it allow updating the app?

Comment: I got the answer